# How to merge elements of two lists at the same index in Python?

Tags: python

im new to python i've just started.
so im trying to merge two lists into each other in one big list.
input:

```
A = [[a,1],[b,2],[c,3]]
B = [10,20,30]
```

desired output:

```
c = [[a,1,10],[b,2,20],[c,3,30]]
```

i tried insert method but it does not add B elements inside each individual list inside the A list
and i tried `c.extend([a,b])` but it gave me this:

```
[10,[a,1],20,[b,2],30,[c,3]]
```

what seems to be the problem because im really confused.
thanks

Comment: zip them together and concat: `[l+[n] for l, n in zip(a, b)]`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. What did you try exactly? I'm really not sure how you got that output. Also, are the variables `a, b, c` meant to be strings? If so they should be in quotes.

Comment: C = [ A[i] + [B[i]] for i in range(len(A))]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the input lists then add them:

```
a = [['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]]
b = [10, 20, 30]

c = [x+[y] for x, y in zip(a, b)]
print(c)  # -> [['a', 1, 10], ['b', 2, 20], ['c', 3, 30]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `c` to be independent of `a`, you'll need to make a deep copy, either with the standard library [copy.deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) or by hand-coding:

```
c = [ai[:] for ai in a]
```

and then extend each element list in `c` with the corresponding value from `b`:

```
for ci, bi in zip(c,b):
    ci.append(bi)
```

which does rely on the structure being exactly as you illustrate: each element of `a` is a list, and each element of `b` is a value.

If you just say `c=a` or `c=a.copy()` to start with, the lists inside `a` will also be affected by the `append` actions.